# Math expressions in JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file with

```
{
        "t": 5550.45, 
         "r": 12.4
}
```

Now I would like to have an element with `Dv= 1.0e-04*np.exp(-300000.0/r/t)`

So my question is can I write Dv as a key value pair like other parameters above?

Comment: load json, do calculation and write it back

Comment: The only valid data types in JSON are strings, numbers, booleans, lists, and dictionaries. You could save your expression as a string and calculate it using `eval`, but keep in mind that it isn't secure because it leaves you vulnerable to injection-type attacks if your json comes from an untrusted source, or is otherwise editable

Answer (score 0):

If you accept that the value of the key is given as a string then you can leverage `eval()`. Note that this opens you up to an attack given by evil data but technically this is possible. See: [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

```py
import numpy

data = {
    "t": 5550.45, 
    "r": 12.4,
    "dv": "1.0e-04 * numpy.exp(-300000.0/data['r']/data['t'])"
}
data["dv"] = eval(data["dv"])

print(data)
```

That will give you:

```
{'t': 5550.45, 'r': 12.4, 'dv': 1.2793161767043818e-06}
```

Alternatively, If you control the "json" you could potentially swap that out for a python dictionary. They look very similar. That would allow you to do something like:

```py
import numpy

data = {
    "t": 5550.45, 
    "r": 12.4,
    "dv": lambda d : 1.0e-04 * numpy.exp(-300000.0/d['r']/d['t'])
}
data["dv"] = data["dv"](data)

print(data)
```